# GitHub CLI clients

Tags: github, github-api, github-cli

I'd like to use GitHub more from the command line and less through the web.

Of course, everything related to Git repos can be done through the [Git client](https://git-scm.com/). But I'd like to also do GitHub-specific things like creating forks or managing pull requests.

Given that GitHub seems to have a pretty comprehensive [API](https://developer.github.com/) with [libraries in many languages](https://developer.github.com/libraries/), I was wondering if there are any good command-line clients out there to interact with GitHub?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Have you had a look at [hub](https://github.com/defunkt/hub) or the official [gh](https://github.com/defunkt/github-gem)?

Comment: Wow, not sure how I missed those -- I guess googling with 'github' for a keyword is a bit difficult. ^^  Thanks!

Comment: Update: I've been using `hub` on a day-to-day basis for a while now, and it's the biggest time-saver.

Comment: there is a new project which aims at saving time and more functionality: [Gush](http://gushphp.org)

Answer (score 6):

For anyone still looking for a tool to access GitHub API v3 from command line, please have a look at my client library written in ruby [github_cli](https://github.com/peter-murach/github_cli).

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to manage releases from the commandline, you can use [github-release](https://github.com/aktau/github-release). It uses the recent [github releases API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/). It's written in golang so you can just download the binary and use it without needing install anything else if you want.

DISCLAIMER: I am the author of github-release.

Answer (score 2):

GitHub now have their own CLI: https://cli.github.com/

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, it's no longer in beta :D

Comment: it's no longer beta.

Answer (score 1):

If you're still not satisfied by the available CLIs like myself, check out the [Gub](http://github.com/owahab/gub) gem.

To get Gub to submit pull-request for issue #123, you need to run the following:

$ gub start 123
This will create a new branch issue-123. Once you're done working on the issue, execute:

$ gub finish
Voila!

Note: I am the author of Gub gem.