# Is that possible to create a new github repository all from command line without browser?

Tags: github, repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to create a remote repo on GitHub from the CLI without ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423777/is-it-possible-to-create-a-remote-repo-on-github-from-the-cli-without-ssh)

Every time I create to a new repo on github, I need to firstly go to the github website to create a repository, then using command line to push my code to that repo on my own pc.
Is that possible to create a new github repository all from command line without browser?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610530/github-cli-clients

Answer (score 1):

As stated by **[a recent change to the GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/changes/2012-9-28-auto-init-for-repositories/)**, it's now possible to **create and initialize a repo a the same time** through your preferred shell.

*"Today we’ve made it easier to add commits to a repository via the GitHub API. Until now, you could create a repository, but you would need to initialize it locally via your Git client before adding any commits via the API."*

*"Now you can optionally init a repository when it’s created by sending true for the* `auto_init` *parameter:"*

```
curl -i -u pengwynn \
 -d '{"name": "create-repo-test", "auto_init": true}' \
 https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

This auto initialization feature also allows one to dynamically add a `.gitignore` file to the repository from the **[.GitHub .gitignore repository](https://github.com/github/gitignore)** by passing the name of the template to the `"gitignore_template"` parameter of the curl request.